# Redirect only one page depending on browser language

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, multilingual

I work on a website that has two languages: English and French.

- Pages available in English are under `/en` in URL
- Pages available in French are under `/fr` in URL

When a user arrives on the homepage, he is redirected to `www.example.com/fr` if its browser is in French, otherwise he is redirected to `www.example.com/en`.

Not all the pages are available in both languages, so there isn't any language redirection on other pages than root.

But I have few pages that I'd like to be redirected according to language. How can I redirect `www.example.com/page` to `www.example.com/en/page` (or `www.example.com/fr/page`)?

**UPDATE:** This is the code we use in `.htaccess` to redirect the home page:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /fr [R=302,L]
```

Comment: How are you currently doing the redirection for the home page? The redirection for the "page" might just require a small addition to the current method?

Comment: To redirect the home page, this is what I do in my .htaccess:
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /fr [R=302,L]

Comment: You should edit your question to add the relevant additional information - this will also help to retain its formatting.

Comment: Is the check against `HTTP_HOST` necessary? Do you host multiple domains on this account?

Answer (score 1):

You  can `%{HTTP: Accept-Language}` variable to detect language of a Web browser.

```
RewriteEngine on
#if browser language is "en"
RewriteCond %{HTTP: Accept-Language} ^en
#redirect /page to /en/page
RewriteRule ^((?!en).+)$ /en/$1 [L,R]
#if browser language is "fr"
RewriteCond %{HTTP: Accept-Language} ^fr
#redirect /page to /fr/page
RewriteRule ^((?!fr).+)$ /en/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: The `Accept-Language` header is unlikely to be exactly equal to "en" or "fr", maybe an open-ended `^en` or `^fr` would be preferable? (Or maybe you do only want to redirect when no other option is given?)

Comment: How do I specify the specific page I want to be redirected? Where would "/page" appears in the different lines you proposed?